# How create "table" responsive for all email client?

Tags: email, responsive-design, html-table, newsletter

I will create a table for my newsletter but I read that each client read in not same way the code...
So I would like to have a `table` that it will be responsive for all email service...

I make a small example..

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0;border-collapse: collapse;vertical-align: top; color: #000000; font-size: 15px; margin-top:25px; font-family: Arial">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="vertical-align: top; height: 40px">
      <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; font-weight: bolder;  border-width: 2px 1px 2px 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: #769e9e; text-align: center; padding: 8px 3px 8px 5px; width: 125px;">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        Vulcano
        <!--[if !mso]><!- - -->
      </td>
      <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; font-weight: bolder; border-width: 2px 2px 2px 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #769e9e; text-align: center; padding: 8px 3px 8px 5px;  width: 100px;">
        Ultima attivita'
        <!--[if !mso]><!- - -->
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="vertical-align: top">
      <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; text-align: left; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: #a8c1c1 #a8c1c1 #a8c1c1 #769e9e; padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px; width: 125px;">
        <!--<![endif]-->Etna
        <!--[if !mso]><!- - -->
      </td>
      <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; text-align: left; border-width: 1px 2px 1px 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #a8c1c1 #769e9e #a8c1c1 #a8c1c1; width: 100px; padding: 3px 0px 3px 8px;">
       <!--<![endif]-->2015
       <!--[if !mso]><!- - -->
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr style="vertical-align: top">
      <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; border-style: solid; border-color: #769e9e; border-width: 1px 1px 2px 2px; width: 125px; padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;">
       <!--<![endif]-->
       <!--[if !mso]><!- - -->
     </td>
     <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; border-style: solid; border-color: #769e9e; border-width: 1px 2px 2px 1px; width: 100px; padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;">
       <!--<![endif]-->
       <!--[if !mso]><!- - -->
     </td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/s7n7exst/

What do yuo think about ?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

Overall, yes -- what you have would work. Your table would collapse in some outlook clients and if you continue adding on to this, you'll want to test your email using Litmus and/or EmailOnAcid to assure consistency.

I've fixed a couple things and now this should work

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;vertical-align: top; color: #000000; font-size: 15px; Margin:25px 0 0 0; font-family: Arial">

  <tr height="40" style="vertical-align: top; height: 40px">
    <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; font-weight: bolder;  border-width: 2px 1px 2px 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: #769e9e; text-align: center; padding: 8px 3px 8px 5px; width: 125px;">Vulcano</td>
    <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; font-weight: bolder; border-width: 2px 2px 2px 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #769e9e; text-align: center; padding: 8px 3px 8px 5px;  width: 100px;">Ultima attivita'</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="vertical-align: top">
    <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word;border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; text-align: left; border-width: 1px 1px 1px 2px; border-style: solid; border-color: #a8c1c1 #a8c1c1 #a8c1c1 #769e9e; padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px; width: 125px;">Etna</td>
    <td valign="middle" style="word-break: break-word; border-collapse: collapse !important;vertical-align: top; text-align: left; border-width: 1px 2px 1px 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #a8c1c1 #769e9e #a8c1c1 #a8c1c1; width: 100px; padding: 3px 0px 3px 8px;">2015</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: But what do you think about my example ? With only css inline is good ?

Comment: @Borja it will work and it's fluid but table may break in some outlook clients